# Правильно ли вызывать OnPropertyChanged из одного другого свойства по отношению к другому свойству?

Tags: c#, wpf

Скажем, у меня есть такой код:

```
 public DbKind SelectedDbKind { get; set; }
 public bool BdNameEnable => SelectedDbKind != DbKind.MSSQL;
```

И в зависимости от того, что выбрали в ComboBox, я хочу делать чего-то недоступным.

Тут напрашивается то, что я должен добавить OnPropertyChanged  в SelectedDbKind , которое будет говорить об изменении BdNameEnable . Можно ли так делать или можно красивее?

Comment: Да, так делать можно, хоть и некрасиво. В качестве альтернативы можете посмотреть [библиотеку](https://github.com/StephenCleary/CalculatedProperties). Автор написал [небольшой разбор](https://github.com/StephenCleary/CalculatedProperties/wiki/Alternatives) имеющихся подходов